# Не получается записать в переменную данные файла

Tags: c++, файлы, fstream

В файле содержится 5 строк, в каждой по 2 символа.

Проблема: Не записываются данные в переменную и она остаётся пустой.

```
char text[50];
ifstream f("text.txt");

while (f.get() != '8')
// (8) - это символ в конце файла.
    f.getline(text, 50);

cout << text << endl;

return 0;
```

Comment: Ну получаете, скорее всего, зацикливание - читаете первый символ строки, если не 8 - до конца строки. Если строки, начинающейся с 8, нет - все, сбой чтения (конец файла), и просто бесконечный ничего не читающий цикл...

Comment: А стандартный способ найти конец файла Вас чем не устроил?

Comment: @Maggot А что это за способ?

Comment: Я просто только новичок, извините за эти костыли с окончанием на '8'